# Roles and Permission Tools for Angular Applications

Tags: angular, authorization

We are building angular application where we are calling our backend REST API for user authentication. this REST API uses windows authentication for user authentication.

Now, we would like to implement Roles and Permissions for our angular app.
Our requirement is as follows

1. Users with read-only access should only be able to read certain pages in our app.
2. Users with write access should be allowed to modify data in a particular page.

Could anyone suggest how can we achieve this ?

May be using some open source tool ?

Regards
Vipul

Comment: Could you provide some code ? What have you already done ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular have a built-in mechanism called [guards](https://angular.io/guide/router) to achieve that - we're using that to check the user permission from a Keycloak server. For example, there is a `CanActivate` guard, which you can see the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).

```js
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          { path: 'crises', component: ManageCrisesComponent },
          { path: 'heroes', component: ManageHeroesComponent },
          { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correclty understood, what you need is to display a button only if the user has the right to edit page.

A Guard is useful if you want to prevent access to a page for a kind of user. According to your post, all users will be able to access to the page. However, not all will be able to edit the page.

I think you will need a [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), to send user datas directly from the route.

This is how it works :

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class MeResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    // This should return user data (take care of sending token too)
    return this.http.get<any>(`${environment.api}/auth`)
  }
}
```

In your routing file you have to right :

```js
{
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    resolve: [ MeResolver ],
}
```

Then, in your component, you can access to resolver with the `route` property like :

```js
export class UserComponent {

  $me: Observable<any> = this.route.data.pipe(map(elem => elem[0]));

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

}
```

With that, you can hide an "Edit" button in your HTML :

```html
<button (click)="edit()" *ngIf="(me$ | async)?.role.admin">EDIT</button>
```